# If no answer has upvotes, should the one with fewest edits appear first?

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-order

I listened to the podcast where Joel and Jeff talked about which answer should appear first in the list.  Originally they had it set up that the one posted first would appear first, then they changed it to a random order if all answers had the same number of votes.

What about making it so answers with fewest edits were listed first if there were no upvotes?  This would put the answers that were well thought out and written in full first, while those who rush to post an answer, then edit it, will be further down the list.

Given the overwhelming disagreement on this topic, does anyone have any suggestions how to fix this kind of issue then?  Or is it infact a non-issue now?  Do people no longer consider this to be a problem with the recent changes made?

Comment: Love the downvoter who can't leave a comment.  Perhaps that should also be tracked on the user like their accept rate.

Comment: @Zoidberg:  Do you really miss the 2 rep that much?  Why do people take these things so personally?  It's a moderation system, not an evaluation of the worth of your soul.

Comment: @Adam Not personally, more of a form of professional respect.  All in the spirit of constructive criticism.

Comment: I downvoted because I don't like the idea and this is meta, and that's generally how dislike of suggestions is registered. If I had a specific point to make about the idea, I would also post an answer. I don't. So I didn't.

Comment: Point taken, and thanks for your comment.

Comment: A few words explaining why you didn't like the idea would have been much more helpful though.

Comment: @trapazza Yes it would be nice but I was just trying not to push my luck, LOL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this would only discourage people from editing. Editing is **good**, and should be encouraged.

Comment: Perhaps those who edit 2 or 3 right after creating?  I think editing is good, when its done thoughtfully and based on feedback.  Those who do edit thoughtfully would probably have some upvotes by the time they edit, and it would put them above other answers anyways.

Comment: While I can't speak for anyone else, there have been times that I've spotted a typo or thought of a better way to say something *after* I've submitted it. Some days, the days I'm feeling more like a 486 in a Pentium world, I spot multiple things in succession. Should I be punished for making my question/answer better?